# Сократить множество if-else

Tags: c#

Есть метод, который принимает строку и в зависимости от строки возвращает кортеж `Tuple` с одним `int` и одним `string` значением. Проблема в том, что если расписать это как `if-else` то получится более 20 вариантов. `switch` не сработает для непостоянного значения, а тернарный оператор - для 2 значений разного типа. Вопрос - как упростить данный метод:

```
public static Tuple<int, string> Divide(string SubClass)
{
    int Level = 0;
    string Class = string.Empty;
    try
    {

        if (SubClass.Contains("investment"))
        {
            Class = "bonds";
            RiscLevel = 2;
            return new Tuple<int, string>(RiscLevel, Class);
        }
        else if (SubClass.Contains("speculation"))
        {
            Class = "bonds";
            RiscLevel = 4;
            return new Tuple<int, string>(RiscLevel, Class);
        }

       // и еще много if-else

        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        BOX.ShowError(ex.Message, ex.Source);
        return null;
    }
}
```

В результате получается огромный массив `if-else`  можно ли его как то сократить, 
 сделать более удобочитаемым?

Comment: самое быстрое и топорное решение: создать `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> dict`. Добавить в них все эти данные и дальше просто брать по ключу `dict[key]`

Comment: Тебе необязательно здесь писать else, если в условии есть return и он туда зайдет - то всё остальное проигнорируется.

Comment: @SultanovShamil Имеет смысл оставить else для наглядности: не надо всматриваться в содержимое каждого блока if, чтобы понять, что они взаимоисключающие.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Материализуйте ваши варианты в виде структуры:

```
class Case
{
    public string SubClass { get; }
    public string Class  { get; }
    public int RiscLevel { get; }
}
```

Соответственно, ваш набор if-else превратится в foreach:

```
Case[] cases = { ... };

// ...

foreach (Case case in cases)
    if (SubClass.Contains(case.SubClass))
        return Tuple.Create(RiscLevel, Class);
return null;
```

Comment: Благодарю за подсказку, очень элегантное решение! вместо `class` использовал `struct`.

Comment: @Сергей Дело вкуса, разница примерно нулевая.

Answer (score 6):

Можно вынести "investment" и "speculation" в отдельный массив и получать нужный через linq:

```
var foo = new [] 
{ 
    //Желательно создать отдельный класс/структуру.
    new { Name = "speculation", RiscLevel = 4, Class = "bonds" },
    new { Name = "investment", RiscLevel = 2, Class = "bonds" },
};
var bar = foo.FirstOrDefault(s => SubClass.Contains(s.Name));
if (bar != null) 
{ 
    return new Tuple<int, string>(bar.RiscLevel, bar.Class);
}
```